# hover issue for table in browser IE9

Tags: css

I have a sever problem in my big application. I am using cshtml table in one of screen and applied css file for that table as follows

```
.kitchen_display_tbl tbody tr.even
{
    background: #FCFBFA;
}

.kitchen_display_tbl tbody tr.odd
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.kitchen_display_tbl tbody tr:hover
{
    background-color: #cbc7bd !important;
}
```

but this is giving problem when I mouse over on the table, the column is expanding like any this and every thing blank.

I don't want to use script or jQuery. This is causing problem only in IE9 not others.

Answer (score 0):

```
.kitchen_display_tbl tbody tr.even
{
    background: #FCFBFA;
}

.kitchen_display_tbl tbody tr.odd
{
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

.kitchen_display_tbl tr.even:hover
{
    background: #cbc7bd !important;
}
.kitchen_display_tbl tr.odd:hover
{
    background: #cbc7bd !important;
}
```

try this code frnd.....

Answer (score 0):

```
.kitchen_display_tbl tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
        background: #FCFBFA;
    }

    .kitchen_display_tbl tr:nth-child(2n) {
        background: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .kitchen_display_tbl tr:hover {
        background-color: #cbc7bd !important;
    }
```

Try this code, it works in IE 9